# AngularJS directive that will look at the value of my ngModel then fire off a function in the controller and be available immediately in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a $scope.quickText(data) function in my controller.  The function reviews the parameter 'data' and looks for any codes (ie: .smoke) and then adds that text to the value of the model.

For instance, if the ngModel value was "Completed smoke assessment" and someone types into the 'textarea' or 'text' input .smoke, it would add "patient smokes.  Completed smoke assessment".  This would be available to see in the view instantly as the user is typing .smoke.  The function works but my directive does not.

```
myApp.directive('gmaEvalQuickText1', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {  
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        quickTextEvaluate: '&',  
    },  
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'gmaController',
    controllerAs: 'gc',
        link: function ($elem, $ctrl,controller) {
        
            $elem.on('input keyup change', function () {
            var val = $elem.val().toString();
            var newVal = gc.quickText(val).toString();

            $ctrl.$setViewValue(newVal);

            $timeout(function () {

                $ctrl.$render();
            
            });

            });

   
        }
    }
    
}]);
```

I am very new to AngularJS so I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to make it work :)

For those who need the answer:

```
Directive:


  myApp.directive('evalQuickText', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
        quicktextevalfct: '='
        },
         link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs, $ctrl) {
  
            $elem.on("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                   
                var val = $elem.val().toString();

                var newVal = $scope.quicktextevalfct(val);

                $ctrl.$setViewValue(newVal + "\n");
                $timeout(function () {

                    $ctrl.$render();

                });           

                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if(event.which === 9) {
                   
                var val = $elem.val().toString();

                var newVal = $scope.quicktextevalfct(val);

                $ctrl.$setViewValue(newVal);
                $timeout(function () {

                    $ctrl.$render();

                });           

                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });

        }   
    };

}]);
```

HTML:

```
eval-quick-text quicktextevalfct="quickTextEvaluate"
```